# Is it possible to move action from one piano into another?

Tags: piano, maintenance, repair

I found an old upright with a sound I like but the action is old and crappy.  Can I transfer the action from another (different) upright into this piano?

Comment: Same make/model - maybe. Different - very little chance, without drastic alterations, I guess.

Comment: At the very least, you'd have to verify the key widths are identical, or the action won't even line up.

Comment: Key width isn't going to be the issue.  You don't have to re-learn how wide an octave stretch is every time you sit at a different piano!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost every piano maker uses their own design for the cast iron frame that resists the string tension, and the specific positioning of the strings.

If the two piano cases have different heights (measured from the ground) then the vertical height of the hammers above the keys will probably be different as well.

Therefore, the chances that you can successfully move an action from one model of piano to another are very small, because the hammers won't line up with the strings.